# How to retrieve children that has particular value to it?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm thinking of building a mobile App that can fetch data based on the tags provided by the user.

The app is about suggesting some Gifts based on user Input. For Example, A user selects Tags : "Male", "Birthday", "under30". The API should able to provide list of items matching this criteria.

```
{
  "gifts" : {
    "\"93c08520-14ea-11e7-855f-e957e315db04\"" : {
      "Description" : "SomeDescription",
      "Name" : "Some GIFT",
      "Tags" : [ "wedding", "graduation", "Easter" ],
      "id" : "93c08520-14ea-11e7-855f-e957e315db04"
    },
    "\"93d48250-14ea-11e7-855f-e957e315db04\"" : {
      "Description" : "SomeDescription",
      "Name" : "Some GIFT",
      "Tags" : [ "birthday", "graduation", "anniversary" ],
      "id" : "93d48250-14ea-11e7-855f-e957e315db04"
    },
    "\"93e487e0-14ea-11e7-855f-e957e315db04\"" : {
      "Description" : "SomeDescription",
      "Name" : "Some GIFT",
      "Tags" : [ "graduation", "wedding", "birthday" ],
      "id" : "93e487e0-14ea-11e7-855f-e957e315db04"
    }
}
```

I came up with this kinda of structure with firebase, and Playing about with orderByValue and OrderByKey.

Please suggest some ways to order my data and ways to retrieve them using Firebase Query Param(RESTful).

Comment: In the future, please post your firebase structure as text please, no images. Text is searchable and we can copy and paste it into an answer without having to re-type. You can get the text from the Firebase dashboard->3 dots in upper right corner, export JSON.

Comment: sure. updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please avoid using arrays. They are very limited; individual elements cannot be accessed and if you need to add, edit or delete anything in the array the entire array must be updated and re-written. See [Arrays Are Evil.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

To answer the question; when you want to query for more than one parameter you need to either

```
1) Nest your queries - can get quite complex
2) Filter in code - with a large dataset can be to much
3) Combine your parameters into a single child.
```

Here's the 3) way. Assume you have a set number of tags:

```
male
female
birthday
age
```

and a structure

```
Gifts
  gift_0
    desc: "asdas"
    name: "assad"
    male: true
    birthday: true
    age: 30
    query: male_birthday_30
  gift_1
    desc: "asdas"
    name: "assad"
    female: true
    anniversary: true
    age: 28
    query: female_anniversary_28
  gift_2
    desc: "asdas"
    name: "assad"
    male: true
    birthday: true
    age: 35
    query: male_birthday_35
```

With this structure you can easily query all gifts for males or females, gifts for people of a certain age or between ages or for birthday or anniversary.

The *query* child node enables you to extend that with the ability to query for male_birthday gifts or female_annivesary gifts but also enables you to capture a range of ages: (here's some pseudo code)

```
query.startingAt("male_birthday_30").endingAt("male_birthday_35")
```

You can extend that farther with a little cross referencing. Let's define a few variables to stand for different combinations of events...

```
  combo0 = birthday
  combo1 = birthday and anniversary
  combo2 = birthday and anniversary and graduation
```

then a gift node would look like this

```
  gift_0
    desc: "asdas"
    name: "assad"
    male: true
    birthday: true
    anniversary: true
    age: 30
    query: male_combo1_30
```

and the query

```
query.startingAt("male_combo1_30").endingAt("male_combo1_35")
```

which would return all gifts for males that are appropriate for birthday and anniversary who are between 30 and 35.

Using that technique you can make some wickedly complex queries.